# Convergence rate of the central limit theorem near the center of the distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, asymptotics, limits-and-convergence, limit-theorems

I'm looking for fast convergence rates for the central limit theorem - when we are not near the tails of the distribution.

Specifically, from the general convergence rates stated in the Berry–Esseen theorem

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem

we know that, under certain conditions, the cumulative probability distribution of the scaled mean of a random sample $F_n(x)$ converges to the cumulative normal distribution $\Phi(x)$ with a convergence rate of $n^{-1/2}$, where n is the sample size.

However, as stated in

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

it is well known that "As an approximation for a finite number of observations, it [the central limit theorem] provides a reasonable approximation only when close to the peak of the normal distribution; it requires a very large number of observations to stretch into the tails."

Therefore, my question is:

If we are given additional assumption that $|x|<C$, where $C$ is some positive constant, can we improve the $n^{-1/2}$ convergence rate of the the Berry–Esseen theorem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edgeworth expansions give extra terms that can be used to estimate the rate of convergence.

Comment: Oh, never heard about these. Indeed they look very relevant. Thanks!

Comment: ALso, if you can hold of P. Hall, Rates of convergence in the central limit theorem, there seems to be quite a lot of theory that is relevant.

Comment: Thanks again. For completeness, I will summarize my conclusions from the answer and all the helpful comments:
1) As a result of the Edgeworth expansion (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgeworth_series): The convergence rate is $n^{-1/2}$, unless the third cumulant of the distribution is zero (as for the uniform distribution).   In that case the convergence rate is $n^{-1}$, unless other cumulants are zero... and so on.
2) The reason that the approximation is bad at the tails is due to its relative precision - since the tails are usually are very small.

Comment: Careful, Davide's example has zero third moment and has convergence rate $n^{-1/2}$.  Probably you are looking at an Edgeworth expansion that excludes lattice distributions.  There is a different expansion for those.

Comment: Oops, I guess I should not rely on Wikipedia too much (just corrected the Edgeworth expansion wiki). Thanks for catching this! True, there is a correction term for lattice distributions (see paper "Edgeworth series for lattice distributions‏"). Unfortunately, this correction is always $n^{-1/2}$ on the lattice points. This is simply because the cumulative distribution (of the scaled distribution) have $O(n^{-1/2})$ jumps between lattice points.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, even in the most favorable case $(X_i)_{i\geqslant 0}$ iid with $\mathbb P(X_i=1)=\mathbb P(X_i=-1)=1/2$. Denoting $F_n$ the cumulative distribution function of $n^{-1/2}S_n$, we have by symmetry 
$$F_{2n}(0)=\frac 12(1+\mathbb P(S_{2n}=0)).$$
Since $\mathbb P(S_{2n}=0)=\binom{2n}n2^{-2n}$, denoting $\Phi$ the cdf of the standard normal distribution, 
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|F_{2n}(x)-\Phi(x)|\geqslant |F_{2n}(0)-\Phi(0)|\geqslant \frac 12\cdot \binom{2n}n2^{-2n}.$$
Using Stirling's formula, we obtain that the RHS behave asymptotically like $n^{-1/2}$.

Comment: I believe you should expect faster convergence if you rule out the lattice distributions, though these are limits of non-lattice distributions.

Comment: Hi Douglas - sounds interesting. Care to explain why this is so (or point to some reference)?

Comment: @Daniel Soudry: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30468/error-in-normal-approximation-to-a-uniform-sum-distribution